# Conditional list options based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I am a newbie on Wordpress working with a theme to make a car platform. Unfortunately, on the theme, the car-selling functionalities differ from what we need. One of those things is: show or hide options based on previous selection with dropdown lists.

Quick example: If 'BMW' is chosen on **'Make'**, then only show '1 series' '3 series' '5 series' on **'Model'**, if '3 series is chosen, then only show 318i 320i 330i on **'Engine'**, aso. From a logical point of view, it is so easy, but I have no clue how to translate this into code. Luckily, I've found pretty good code here already, but this works only for the next dropdown list. My question is, how does the javascript/jquery code have to look like so you can make **more than 2 conditional dropdown lists**? You could take Engine as an example. Thank you

**HTML code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="req_make">Make</label>
<select id="req_make" name="make">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Choose Make</option>
    <option class="BMW" value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="Audi">Audi</option>
    <option class="VW" value="VW">VW</option>
</select>

<label for="req_model">Model</label>
<select id="req_model" name="model">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Choose model</option>
    <option class="BMW" value="1er">1er</option>
    <option class="BMW" value="3er">3er</option>
    <option class="BMW" value="5er">5er</option>
    <option class="BMW" value="7er">7er</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="A4">A4</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="A8">A8</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="Q7">Q7</option>
    <option class="VW" value="Golf">Golf</option>
    <option class="VW" value="Touran">Touran</option>
</select>

<label for="req_engine">Engine</label>
<select id="req_engine" name="engine">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Choose engine</option>
<option class="BMW" value="7er">7er - 730i</option>
<option class="BMW" value="7er">7er - 730Li</option>
<option class="BMW" value="7er">7er - 735i</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#req_make").on("change",function(){
        var levelClass = $('#req_make').find('option:selected').attr('class');
        console.log(levelClass);
        $('#req_model option').each(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            if (self.hasClass(levelClass) || typeof(levelClass) == "undefined") {
                self.show();
            } else {
                self.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you'll have to eventually learn how to do some javascript to get to that result, or find a plugin that does exactly what you want. Messing around with code when you don't know what you are doing is generally a bad idea and you'll lose time.

Comment: I disagree with that. With a little bit of knowledge of HTML and PHP, I could change so much already. I even have a theory of what the problem is or what has to be changed here: since 'class' stays same throughout the lists, it is not possible to make the the next dropdown conditional based on that. I already tried 'value' instead, but of course, it didn't work since I don't know which parts to change exactly.

So the conditional dropdown list is basically the only thing left, and it will take me more time to go through Javascript and jQuery instead of someone just changing the code.

Comment: Actually, I just did it. It is working, but of course I don't know if it's the right way to do it. I am taking the value of the former list and assigning it to the class of the next, while changing `attr('class')` to `attr('value')`. https://jsfiddle.net/agdkw1xm/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. So change `$('#req_model option').each(function () { ...` to `$('#req_model option, #req_engine option').each(function () { ...` to solve this.

Comment: Hey man, thx for your help. But maybe you misunderstood sth., I checked your code and it is not working the way I mean. I just posted a solution, see above, but I have no clue if it is the right way to do it. The aim is to get more specific with the dropdown lists(conditional-> conditional->conditional...etc) 5 times maybe, not getting more general.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it on my own. It is working, but of course I don't know if it's the right way to do it. I am taking the value of the former list and assigning it to the class of the next, while changing `attr('class')` to `attr('value')`. https://jsfiddle.net/agdkw1xm/